# Taylor series in a total derivative?

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am trying to understand the impact of Taylor series over total derivatives. Suppose I have the following equation

$$
\begin{align}
dA&=dB\\
dA&=k_1+k_2dB+k_3(dB)^2+k_3(dB)^3+...\tag{Taylor series of $dB$}
\end{align}
$$

What is the significance of the constant term $k_1$? Before the Taylor series, it is somewhat straightforward to solve the equation as one simply integrates both side. 
$$
\begin{align}
\int{dA}&=\int{dB}\\
A&=B+c \tag{c is an integration constant}
\end{align}
$$
But with the $k_1$ constant, it is not clear to me. With the Taylor series, I get
$$
\begin{align}
\int{dA}&=\int{k_1}+\int{k_2db}+...
\end{align}
$$
Now, what about the next term, do I pose $\iint{k_3(db)^2}$, or do I pose $\left(\int{k_3db}\right)db$? What about $\int{k_1}$, does it diverges?